# How to set queue limit for response object of multiprocessing pool

Tags: python

z() is a really fast generator, faster than do() can process them. is there a way to queue the 'results' object? what attributes of this object? this is what I did, i setup a queue internally to queue the 'results', is there a better way???

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
import Queue,time,random
from datetime import datetime


class rob:
    def __init__(self,maxq):
            self.count = 0
            self.q = Queue.Queue(maxq)
            self.maxq = maxq
    def add(self,x=1):
        self.count += x

    def z(self):
        while True:
            #s = random.choice(range(1,6))
            #time.sleep(.1)
            t = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S.%f")
            self.add()

            t = t+'---'+str(self.count)
            #print 'z:',t
            if self.q.full():
                print 'waiting'
            self.q.put(t)

            yield t

    def do(self,t):
        secs = random.choice(range(1,10))
        #could take max of 10 seconds per do()
        time.sleep(secs)
        d = self.q.get()
        return t
                #print e.message, e.args
#patch_send()       


mt = 100


b = rob(mt*3)
pool = ThreadPool(mt) #because u can 
results = pool.imap_unordered( b.do, b.z() )
#pool.close()

for r in results:
    print r
```

Comment: Increase `maxq`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue

Comment: are you understanding the question? maxq was my workaround. i was asking about the object that gets returned from pool.imap..... this obviously is unlimited

Comment: Why do you show us code that contains a workaround and not the code that illustrates your real problem? Do you want to use `Queue` or do you want to get rid of it?